# How to test a component with @Input and type Observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am little new to writing unit tests for Angular and not able to figure out how I can write unit tests for a component with a @Input directive.

Here is my

== file.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bugs-table',
  templateUrl: './bugs-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bugs-table.component.scss']
})
export class BugsTableComponent implements OnInit {
//   priorityData: any = [];
  @Input() bugsDataService;
  @Input() gridItemComponent;
  constructor(
  ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
this.bugsDataService.subscribe(response => {
  this.bugsData = response;
})
```

}
    }

## Here is my file.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, BrowserXhr } from "@angular/http";

fdescribe('BugsTableComponent', () => {
  let component: BugsTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BugsTableComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BugsTableComponent ],
      imports: []
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BugsTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But it fails with error:

> × should create
>         HeadlessChrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10.0.0)
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I know this is because bugsDataService (which is a observable) is undefined.
Can any please help fixing this. 
Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: First of all why do you input a service? The service should be injected. Secondly, have you tried setting `component.bugsDataService` ?

Comment: actually this is an Observable data. (yes, kind of service)... but this is how it is. 
component.bugsDataService : can you show an exmaple please.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?  I suspect your beforeEach functions were not executing.

Answer (score 4):

the following works:

Include this import:

`import { of } from 'rxjs';`

Change the beforeEach block for the file to:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BugsTableComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  // needed because ngAfterViewInit gets called and if there isn't an observable to subscribe to it will fail
  component.bugsDataService = of(null);

  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Write a test:

```
it('Should assign the input value to bugsdata', () => {
  // Arrange
  component.bugsData = {}; // to make sure it's empty at the start
  const resultFromService = {hello: 'world'};
  component.bugsDataService = of(resultFromService); // this creates an observable from resultFromService

  // Act
  component.ngAfterViewInit();

  // Assert
  expect(component.bugsData).toEqual(resultFromService);
});
```

---

Some notes:

- I've noticed is that your component has a `ngAfterViewInit` but the class does not implement it. If you're not using `ngOnInit` then replace it in the class declaration with `ngAfterViewInit` and update the imports.
- If you don't want to do the change I suggested in the beforeEach block you can move the subscribe line from `ngAfterViewInit` to a separate method that is called by `ngAfterViewInit`. However, you'll then need to spy on it so it doesn't actually get called.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BugsTableComponent ],
      imports: [],
      providers: [BugsDataService] // inject service here 
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

This should fix the bug but

If you want to Simulate the actual behaviour of the service better way would be to create a mock service which extends BugsDataService and use it in the unit test cases to provide Mock Data

example

```
@Injectable()
export class BugsDataMockService extends BugsDataService {

overridenMethod() {
return Observable.of( { data : yourmockresponse });
}


And in your Spec file (Unit test)
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BugsTableComponent ],
      imports: [],
      providers: [ { provide: BugsDataService, useClass: BugsMockDataService } ] // Use Mock Service instead of original one 
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```